# DLL Load Fail While Importing QtCore, QtGui

Tags: pyqt4

guys
 I recently heard about PyQt4 and decided I should give it a try, however, importing gave me some errors. When I tried importing QtCore and QtGui, I received this error:

```
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I am using python 3.6.0 on my windows 32 bit computer
I installed pyqt4 by using

```
pip install pyqt4-4.11.4-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
```

To solve this problem I looked into my site-packages and I did see

Comment: You could try PyQt5 if you don't require the older version.

Comment: @101  Sorry PyQt 5 does not have QwebView

Answer (score 0):

You should use PyQt5. I know it doesn't have **QWebView**, but it has a extra module called **QWebEngineView**. You can install it by running this in the terminal:
`pip install PyQtWebEngine`. This is the code I use:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 
web = QWebEngineView()
web.load(QUrl(url))
web.setZoomFactor(2)
web.zoomFactor()
web.show()
 
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```